# No database selected using Python and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

1. below error showed in the code

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\91798\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-
   packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 555, in cmd_query
   self._cmysql.query(
   enter code here_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: No database selected

````
import csv
import database as db

PW = "Shivani@27me"
ROOT = "root"
DB = "ecommerce_record" 
LOCALHOST = "localhost"

RELATIVE_CONFIG_PATH = '../config/'

USER = 'users'
PRODUCTS = 'products'
ORDER = 'orders'

    create_users_table = """
    create table if not exists users(
        user_id varchar(10) primary key,
        user_name varchar(45) not null,
        user_email varchar(45) not null,
        user_password varchar(45) not null,
        user_address varchar(45) null,
        is_vendor tinyint(1) default 0
    )
    """

connection = db.create_server_connection(LOCALHOST, ROOT, PW)

# creating the schema in the DB

    db.create_and_switch_database(connection, DB, DB)
    print("1.a problem complted")
    print("/n")
    print("1.b")
    print("initiating creation of table")
    db.create_table(connection,create_users_table)
    print("user table created")
    with open(RELATIVE_CONFIG_PATH + USER + '.csv', 'r') as f:
        val = []
        data = csv.reader(f)
        for row in data:
            val.append(tuple(row))
        sql = """
        insert into users(user_id,user_name,user_email,user_password,user_address, is_vendor)
        values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
        """
        val.pop(0)
        db.insert_many_records(connection,sql,val)
    print("User data insertion in table done")

    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error reflected, before executing your SQL query, you need to select the database using the query `use db_name`, which would select the desired database and execute your queries on the same. Or as an alternative to this, you could also use the `mysql.connector` library.

```py
import mysql.connector as sql

DB_HOST = 'localhost'
DB_USER = 'root'
DB_PASS = 'Shivani@27me'
DB_NAME = 'ecommerce_record'

dbConnection = sql.connect(host = DB_HOST, user = DB_USER, passwd = DB_PASS, database = DB_NAME)
dbCursor = dbConnection.cursor()
dbCursor.execute('<YOUR SQL QUERY>')
dbCursor.commit()
```

Also, as a secure coding practice, try defining critical variables in your environment. Hope this helps!